# Is it possible to get a preview in the default print-dialog-window ? or at least a "preview" button?

Tags: printing

The default print-dialog window of ubuntu 20.04 does not offer preview. Is there any way to change that ? At least I would like a preview button, but i would rather like it to appear by default.

Thanks,
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the print preview option under the File menu?

Comment: i don't see any file menu in the screenshot i gave. What do you mean ?

Comment: Cancel this screen and look at the main screen of Firefox or Evince (or whatever application you are running, which you haven't said).

Comment: I wanted to use it through firefox, libreoffice, evince, okular and others. And i felt like it was more simple if the preview was in the "print" screen already.
Your solution works though i can generate a preview and then print it.
But is there a way to add like an add-on to have the preview directly?

Comment: Firefox, Evince, LibreOffice and Okular have different print dialogs. All their developers would have to co-operate to implement what you want. I do not see that happening.

Comment: the best intermediate soution I found was to print in a file and preview that pdf file before sending it to the printer...

Comment: I second the need for this. A print preview should be available in the system print dialog to be application agnostic and to visualize the effects of custom page sizing which is handled in the system print dialog

Answer (score 0):

"In the 1990s and 2000s, most apps provided print UI using a Print dialog, sometimes a separate Print Preview window, and (for documents with persistent page layout) a Page Setup dialog. This made architectural sense for slow PCs, because it allowed the operating system to provide a consistent Print dialog, and rendering the print preview was often a slow process.

AbiWord is an example of this traditional model: a Print dialog, a separate Print Preview window, and a separate Page Setup dialog (not shown).

But for users, this approach was error-prone, inefficient, and complex. Error-prone, because if the print preview was requested before the Print dialog, it failed to show the effects of settings changed in the Print dialog, contributing to mistaken choices. Inefficient, because even when Print dialog choices could be previewed, this usually resulted in the Print dialog disappearing and needing to be reopened later — and/or the preview was a static PDF that didn’t update to reflect later choices. And complex, because it resulted in an app’s “File” menu containing two or three menu items devoted to printing, rather than just one." - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Printing#Print_dialog